# How to think of algebraic geometry in characteristic p?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, soft-question, arithmetic-geometry

How does a working mathematician usually think about algebraic geometry in characteristic $p$? For the sake of concreteness, and to make things more "geometric" (whatever that means), let's say we work over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$. It seems to me that (motivated by the étale topology, say), authors tend to use the geometry of $\mathbb{C}$ as a template, envisioning $\mathbb{A}^1$ as something like the complex plane. Then, using this as a model, one accounts for extra phenomena that occur in characteristic $p$; namely, extra automorphisms due to frobenii, as well as some extra singularities that don't occur in characteristic $0$.

Is this picture of characteristic $p$ geometry accurate? To make this question a little less soft, I'll ask the following naive, and certainly false question:
Is the category of varieties over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ equivalent to the category of varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ along with extra morphisms coming from Frobenii (as well as objects obtained from glueing via these extra morphisms)?

Comment: I tend to think of characteristic $p$ algebraic geometry as both similar and different to the complex algebraic geometry, but this probably doesn't answer your question...Turning to the less soft question, supersingular elliptic curves have endomorphism rings much larger than elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$, so I don't see how to make an equivalence of categories along the lines you're suggesting.

Comment: Are you asking for the best visual image of the geometric space of $\mathbb{A}^1$ in characteristic $p$?  Or are you asking how we use special features of algebraic geometry in positive characteristic to help us prove theorems?  In many ways a closer "geometric analogy" of $\mathbb{A}^n$ over a field like $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ is a fibration over a punctured complex disk where the fibers are isomorphic to affine space.  Frobenius is analogous to analytic continuation along a (fraction of a) loop in the disk.

Comment: @JasonStarr I'm primarily interested in just visualizing $\mathbb{A}^1$, along with any other varieties over a field of characteristic $p$. Though admittedly I hope that such a visualization would help to understand theorems in positive characteristic. 
Could you elaborate on the analogy you laid out? Or point me toward a reference which discusses this analogy in detail; I've never heard of this interpretation.

Comment: It is not an interpretation; it is just an analogy.  The absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{F}_p$ equals the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{C}((t))$.  Also, both fields are "quasi algebraically closed" fields.

Comment: @JasonStarr, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453734/how-to-think-of-algebraic-geometry-in-characteristic-p#comment1174127_453734), what is the difference between "quasi algebraically closed" and "pseudo-finite"?